# One inch margin not printing out as specified in the Latex code

Tags: margins

I am trying to format my dissertation for ETD submission. One requirement is that the left, right, bottom and top margins all have to be exactly 1". I have specified that in the Latex code and when it displays on the screen the requirements look right however when I print the document the left/right margin is not a 1" margin (it's a little more). The top/bottom margin is exactly 1". I am printing the document as fit from Adobe pdf. How do I get it so that the margin prints out as specified in the code? I have changed the type of paper dimension from a4paper to letter but that did not change anything.

One some pages, such as the Acknowledgements/Table of Content I need a 2" margin from the top and I did not know how to specify that so I used "vspace" to push down the text, so I know my code is not great. I appreciate your help.

[image]

[image]

```
\linespread{1.5}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath} 
\usepackage{csvsimple}
%\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
%Margin was changed here
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 8in},margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}


\doublespacing


\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\csname phantomsection\endcsname\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}}{}{}




\addto\captionsenglish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    { \center     \vspace{15mm} \normalsize TABLE OF CONTENTS}%
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother




\pagenumbering{roman}

 
\begin{document}
\long\def\/*#1*/{}






 \linespread{1.1}
 
 



\vspace{200mm}





\begin{center}
    
    
    
  
       \textbf{ \hphantom{Thesis Title}}
        
        \vspace{1.6cm}
   
    
    
     \textbf{ Thesis on Weather Modeling }
        
     \large
    \vspace{2.1cm}
    Jess Gradstudent
    
\vspace{1.2cm}    
    

   
\end{center}

\singlespacing
A dissertation submitted to the faculty of the University of Nottingham  in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy in the Department of Mathematics.


\doublespacing
\begin{center}
    
  
        
     \large
    \vspace{2cm}
    University of Nottingham
    
    \vspace{-0.7cm}
    
    2021
    
\vspace{2.4cm}    
      \setlength{\leftskip}{12.5cm}
      Approved by:  \\ \vspace{0.35cm}
      Professor Johnson \\  \vspace{0.35cm}
      Professor Smith \\  \vspace{0.35cm}
      Professor Brown \\  \vspace{0.35cm}
      Professor Jones \\   \vspace{0.35cm}
      Professor Williams \\
      
     
\end{center}


\vspace{200mm}


\vspace{20cm}
\textbf{ \hphantom{Thesis Title}}
\begin{center}

\vspace{18.9    cm}

\singlespace

© 2021\\
Jess Gradstudent\\
ALL RIGHTS RESERVED



\end{center}


\vspace{200mm}

\vspace{200mm}

\begin{center}
    
    
    \Large
  
       \textbf{ \hphantom{Thesis Title}}
        
        \vspace{1.9cm}
   
    \normalsize
    
    \textbf{ ABSTRACT }
        
     \large
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    Jess Gradstudent: Thesis on Weather Modeling
    
    (Under the direction of Professor Johnson)
       
    \vspace{0.0cm}
   
\end{center}


\lipsum[2-10]

\vspace{200mm}

\vspace{200mm}

\begin{center}
     
       \textbf{ \hphantom{Thesis Title}}
        
        \vspace{1.8cm}
    
    \textbf{ ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS }
       
   
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]

\vspace{200mm}
%\singlespacing
\tableofcontents
%\doublespacing
\vspace{200mm}
\begin{center}
 \renewcommand{\listtablename}{\normalsize LIST OF TABLES}
\listoftables
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\normalsize LIST OF FIGURES}
\listoffigures
\end{center}
\vspace{200mm}
\section{ Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\lipsum[2-10]
\section{Data}  
\lipsum[2-10]
\section{Model}  
\end{document}$
```

Comment: Perhaps there could be a non-zero "Crop Size" in the "Document" preferences in your Adobe.

Comment: I tried playing around with the printer setting. One adobe printing option did help "Choose paper source by PDF page size". This changed the setting of the paper size to 8.27 x 11.69 inches instead of the default letter paper of 8.5 x 11 inches. Maybe I need to change the size of the paper in the Latex document?

Comment: A4 is 8-1/4 x 11-3/4 in, or 210 x 297 mm (with a fraction less where the printer can't reach). Try matching the document paper size in your tex file to the physical paper size the printer is using: that is, letter to letter, or A4 to A4.

Comment: On the title page etc. there is extra space being added inside the text area, which has to be dealt with on a case by case basis.  If you add the [showframe] option to geometry, it will show you where the margins are.